# Is there a way in CSS to move an element in the DOM

Tags: css

I think this is very unlikely but is there any way in CSS to achieve moving elements in the DOM? Like moving jt-menu-item-price into the jt-header in the following?

```
<div class='jt-row'>
  <div class='jt-header'>this is what I need done</div><div class='jt-menu-item-price'>37.23</div>
</div>

<div class='jt-row'>
  <div class='jt-header'>this is what I need done<div class='jt-menu-item-price'>37.23</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using CSS, no. You can manipulate the DOM using JavaScript, but not with CSS. You could 'visually' move it with CSS, but that wouldn't affect the DOM structure, just how it is presented.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Javascript to manipulate the DOM. CSS never affects the DOM, just let you style it.